# Flutter FOR loop inside widget

Tags: flutter, dart

So essentially what  I am trying to achieve is this:

[image]

But apparently its not allowed in flutter.

I'm trying to load a LIST of restaurant items and their quantity values using a FOR loop and display them unto the app with a text widget. But with the current logic that I used I need to iterate and update the variable of *x* and *range* after displaying each item name along with its quantity from their respective lists. The problem here is I can't use the FOR loop within widgets as you would a normal FOR loop where you can place multiple *statements* within the FOR loop.

**The snippet of code below is the logic I'm trying to achieve. It is similar to the code I'm implementing in flutter. The FOR loop portion is the only portion I'm kind of stuck with.**

Still kind of new to Flutter, so any help or guidance would be appreciated. Thank you!

```
void main()
{
 int x =0;
  int range =0;
  
  
  
  List<String> restaurauntNames = ['Jollibee','Chowking','Mcdonalds'];
  
 List<int> orderNumber = [3,2,1];
  
 List<int> itemQuantity = [1,1,2,3,1,3];
  
 List<String> itemName= ['Jolly Spag','Chicken Joy','Peach Mango Pie','Chao Fan','Lauriat','Big Mac'];
  
 
  

  for(String i in restaurauntNames)
  {
    print(i);
    for(int z =0; z!=orderNumber[x];z++)
    {
      print(itemName[z+range]+'---------------'+ itemQuantity[z+range].toString());
    }
    range = range + orderNumber[x];
    x++;
  }
```

Comment: Can you paste your code, not the screenshot!

Comment: please post your code instead of pictures

Comment: Oh noted, I'll edit my question and add a snippet of some of the code.

Comment: I've now edited and added portions of the code I'm trying to implement :)

Answer (score 4):

You can't put brace in for loop widget, I've got the same problem for quite some time and one the solution was to map the iterated list.

```
children: [
    ...restaurantNames.map((i){
      print(i);
      for(int z = 0; z != loadedOrder.orderNumber[x];z++){
        return Text(loadedOrder.itemNames[z + range] + 'X' +loadedOrder.itemQuantity[z + range].toString());
      }
      range = range + orderNumber[x];
      x++;
    }).toList(),
  ],
```